# prepopulate cin before reading it

Tags: c++, console

I am writing a program in C++ (in Borland C++ builder 6.0) that reads and displays customer data through cin and cout and stores and reads it to and from a database (sqlite).
It uses a console for interaction with the user.

What I want to achieve is that the user can update customer data that has been written previously into the database (e.g. data like name, address, etc)

When the user is going to update customer data, I want to let him go through the same steps/data as when creating a customer, but now, the data that the user wants to enter or modify has been prepopulated (as read from the database) and already displayed on the console, i.e. written into the input buffer cin, like it was typed in by the user. The user then only needs to hit enter to go to the next step/data and leave the data as it was. If the user needs to change or updata the data, he needs to change the data that was read from the database and displayed, but can modify it as he likes after which it will be written/updated into the database.

I hope it's clear what I mean.

Comment: That won't allow the user to edit the input tho', which I take "prepopulate cin" to mean - if you want to edit a misspelled "Mets" to "Mats", you should be able to do that without typing the whole thing in again - unless I misuonderstood the question.

Comment: @seth, your link describes how to overwrite output thrown out by cout, what I want to achieve here is to prepopulate cin, as it was like being typed in by the user, but retrieved from the data base instead, and then being manipulated by the user if he wants or just hit enter to leave the data unchanged and stored into cin.

Comment: You're right, unfortunately I can't undo a close vote.

Comment: I think an answer for this lies here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550499/2219808.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done (trivially - almost anything CAN be done if you just put enough effort into it, the trick is to know when to put the effort on doing it a better way!) with cin/cout. You are much better off using some sort of `text-mode UI library`, such as ncurses or similar.

I have written a lot of code that did something similar, but I wrote my own set of functions to manage cursor position, input of data with validation, selecting things from lists, etc, etc. You will probably have to do SOME of that.

I would also suggest that you at least consider using a more modern compiler.

Comment: Something that comes to my mind is when I would be able to intercept keyboard input. I would be able to fake keyboard input and feed to cin and give controll back to the keyboard once the data from the database has been read and fed into cin?

Comment: That's just making life very complicated. It's much easier to just give up on using `cin` and `cout` which offers very little in way of control over how it works, and use a library that gives you full control over keyboard input and screen output - such as one of the curses libraries. With the added avantage that you can use it on any other curses-compatible platform.

Comment: I just read an article about ncurses. It's mainly used to arrange and manipulate the output on your console screen. It doesn't provide facilities (the article at least didn't mention anything about it) to manipulate (prepopulate as I called it before) the input. The trick that I would like to achieve is that the user input is read first from the data base (like it was typed in by the user himself) after which the user may or may not change it. Need to search a bit further...

Comment: No, the point is that you write a function that can handle string input at a given position of the screen. As part of the function, a string of "current value" can be provided, as well as rules such as "must be integer", "must be decimal value with two decimal points", etc. There isn't a way that you can do what you are asking, without a lot of hacking around in the guts of the IO methods inside cin. It's not how you go about writing a good, user friendly program - you'll also want to be able to go back and edit the text on the line above after having pressed enter, right? That sort of thing..

Comment: It indeed needs hacking arround cin and maybe on a lower level too. That's not worth the effort. It's indeed about user friendlyness, as it would be very useful what I want to achieve. It will probably endup with something like: if the user just hits enter, the existing value will be copied or left unchanged, but what if the user wants to erase the existing value? In a windows environment for instance, the user can click on the value displayed, change it and hit enter to store it. The conclusion is that in a console program, cin doesn't provide these facilities.

Comment: It is however worth to have a further look into ncurses for make up and formatting text in the console. thanks,

Comment: It is about 50 lines of code to do a function that handles "input a string here", with nice editing functions and ability to move to the previous/next field [assuming we have a list of fields]. It's not very hard to do, really. Just takes a "non-echo input" and some other basic curses functions. Start by writing something that can just read a string with no echo, and you are halfway there.